# libopencv_gpu is not available

Tags: opencv, compilation, cmake, opencv3.0

I have installed `OpenCV-3.0` in my `jetson-tk1` board using following cmake command.

```
cmake -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN="3.2" -DCUDA_ARCH_PTX="" -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF ..
```

After make install, I was not able to find `libopencv_gpu`.

In opencv lib path libopencv_gpu is not available.

Due to this I am getting `undefined reference to cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload()`

Can anybody tell what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenCV 3.0 gpu module was split onto several modules: `cudaarithm`, `cudafilters`, `cudaimgproc`, `cudaoptflow`, etc. Also `gpu` namespace was renamed to `cuda`.

So you need to link with `libopencv_core`, which contains `GpuMat` definition and with other cuda modules: `libopencv_cudaarithm`, etc.

Comment: then what will be the possible reasons for `undefined reference to cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload()`

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV3.0 has merged gpu module into cuda namespace. Try using `cv::cuda::GpuMat`. Moreover, make sure you add `opencv2/core/cuda.hpp` and link cuda libraries in the linker.

For further reference you can check this [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/cuda/doc/data_structures.html)